# How do I reorder based on descending order for a specific variable in a grouped bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reorder the graph bars based on one of the variables, in this case the y variable in descending order instead of the alphabetical order of x.

```
x<-c("Jan","Feb","Mar")
y <- c(2000, 23400, 26800)
z<-c(1100,5000,6000)
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
View(df)

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df.long<-melt(df)
ggplot(df.long,aes(x=x, y=value,fill=variable))+geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.9)
```

[image: The current plot that I have is this:]

[image: I am hoping to plot a graph like this below:]

The first plot is before reordering using the script above, and I am hoping to plot a graph similar to the second one. I would really appreciate some guidance here. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. You can use `reorder()` function to arrange data in `x` based on the reshaped values. Here the code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

#Data
df.long<-melt(df)
#Plot
ggplot(df.long,aes(x=reorder(x,-value),
                   y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.9)+
  xlab('Month')+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

Output:

[image]